# Solve the Triangular Inequility by using another method

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Today there was inequility of comples number in my class. Sir asked me to prove that
$$||a|-|b||\le|a-b|$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers
$$$$
and solve it using this method
$$$$
firt prove left hand side
$$|a-b|^2=(a-b)\overline{(a-b)}$$
$$=(a-b)(\overline{a}-\overline{b})$$
$$=a\overline{a}-a\overline{b}-b\overline{a}+b\overline{b}$$
$$=a^2-a\overline{b}-b\overline{a}+b^2 \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ a\overline{a}=a^2$$
and right hand side
$$||a|-|b||^2=(|a|-|b|)\overline{(|a|-|b|)}$$
$$=(|a|-|b|)(\overline{|a|}-\overline{|b|})$$
$$=|a|\overline{|a|}-|a|\overline{|b|}-|b|\overline{|a|}+|b|\overline{|b|}$$
$$=|a|^2-|a|\overline{|b|}-|b|\overline{|a|}+|b^2| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ as \ \overline{|a|}=|a|$$
$$=|a|^2-|a\overline{b}|-|b\overline{a}|+|b^2| \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ as \ |a||b|=|ab|$$
$$\ge a^2-a\overline{b}-b\overline{a}+b^2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ as \ |a|\ge a \ and \ |a|^2=a^2$$
$$=|a-b|^2$$
So
$$||a|-|b||^2 \ge |a-b|^2$$
Taking square root
$$||a|-|b|| \ge |a-b|$$

Comment: $a \overline a$ is $|a|^2$, not $a^2$ ...

Comment: @MartinR but $|a|^2=a^2$ so we can write $a\overline{a}=a^2$

Comment: "|a|^2 = a^2"  not if a isn't real it isn't.  "$a\overline a = a^2$" *absolutely* !!!NOT!!! true if a is not real.

Comment: For example if $a=3+4i$ then $|a|^2=25$ but $a^2=-7+24i$

Comment: *Any* $a = x + i y$ where $y \ne 0$ is a counter example.  $(x + i y)^2 = (x^2 - y^2) + 2xy i$ but $a\overline a = (x + i y)(x - i y) = a^2 + b^2$.  Never equal (unless y = 0 and $a  \in \mathbb R$).

Comment: In reals, |a|^2 = a^2 *ONLY* because all squares are positive so a^2 has to be positive as does |a|^2.  In complex numbers, however, a^2 doesn't have to be positive and if it isn't positive than it *can't* be equal to |a|^2.

Comment: Also tell me what is the solution..... to prove such triangular inequility...

Comment: What is true is that $|a^2| = |a|^2$.

Comment: Also |a| >= a, isn't true.  As a is a complex number there is no order.  You can only compare reals to reals.

Answer (score 0):

You must disabuse yourself of the notion $|a|^2 = a\overline a = aa = a^2$ immediately.

In fact the idea should seem utterly absurd and obviously false.

If $a = x + i y$ and $y \ne 0$ (in other words, if $a \not \in \mathbb R$) then $a = x + iy$ and $\overline a = x - iy$ and $x +iy \ne x - iy$.  So $a \ne \overline a$ so $a*a \ne a*\overline a$.  How could it? It's absurd.

Furthermore:

If $c \in \mathbb R^+$ then $c$ has exactly two square roots, $\pm \sqrt{c}$, *both* of which are real numbers.

So conversely, if $a \not \in \mathbb R \implies a^2 \not \in \mathbb R^+$. $|a|$, no matter how it was constructed was defined to be a positive number.  So if $a \not \in \mathbb R$ then $a^2 \ne |a|^2 \in \mathbb R^+$.

And finally, if $a = x + iy; y \ne 0$ then $a^2 = (x^2 - y^2) + 2xy i$ (which is real only if x is 0, in which case this is a negative number).  $\overline a = x - iy$ so $a\overline a = (x + iy)(x - iy) = x^2 + y^2$ (which is a positive real number).  These numbers are not equal.

Sorry to beat a dead horse, but this is *important*.

So...

Let $a = x + iy; b = w + iz$.

$|a - b|^2 = |(x - w) + (y - z)i|^2 = (x - w)^2 + (y - z)^2 = x^2 + w^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2(xw + yz)$

while

$||a| - |b||^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 - 2|ab| = x^2 + y^2 + w^2 + z^2 - 2|(x + iy)(w + iz)| = $

$x^2 + y^2 + w^2 + z^2 - 2|(xw - yz) + i(yw + xz)| = x^2 + y^2 + w^2 + z^2 - 2\sqrt{(xw - yz)^2 + (yw + xz)^2} = x^2 + y^2 + w^2 + z^2 - 2\sqrt{x^2w^2 + y^2z^2+y^2w^2 + x^2z^2} $

So the result is true iff $\sqrt{x^2w^2 + y^2z^2+y^2w^2 + x^2z^2} \ge (xw + yz)$

And $(xw + yz)^2 = x^2w^2 + y^2z^2 + 2xywz$ while $\sqrt{x^2w^2 + y^2z^2+y^2w^2 + x^2z^2}^2 = x^2w^2 + y^2z^2+y^2w^2 + x^2z^2$

So result is true iff $y^2w^2 + x^2z^2 \ge 2xywz$

which is true iff $y^2w^2 + x^2z^2 - 2xywz = (yw - xz)^2 \ge 0$.

And as $x,y,w,z \in \mathbb R$, it is.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show 
$$\lvert z + w \rvert \le \lvert z \rvert+ \lvert w\rvert.$$
Since the norm is always positive this will be equivalent to showing the inequality of the squares of both sides.
$$ \lvert z + w \rvert^2 \le \lvert z \rvert^2 + \lvert w\rvert^2 + 2\lvert z \rvert \lvert w \rvert.$$

Where do we start?
$$ \lvert z + w \rvert^2 = (z+w)\overline{(z+w)} = (z+w)(\overline z+ \overline w) = z\overline z + w \overline z + z\overline w + w\overline w = \lvert z \rvert^2 + \lvert w \rvert ^2 + w\overline z + z \overline w$$
Showing
$$ w\overline z + z \overline w \le 2\lvert z \rvert \lvert w \rvert $$
will finish the proof. (The quantity on the left must be real, so we can write an inequality.)

Now write $z = a + bi$ and $w = c + di$. Showing $$(a-bi)(c+di) + (a+bi)(c-di) \le 2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$$ will complete the argument.
Expand the lefthand side. As we hoped, the imaginary terms disappear and we're left with
$$ 2(ac+bd) \le 2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2} $$
If $ac+bd < 0$ we're done automatically, so we can square both sides without missing out on anything fun.
$$ a^2c^2 + b^2d^2 + 2abcd \le a^2c^2 + b^2d^2 + a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 $$
So now we have to show
$$ 2abcd \le a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 \implies 0 \le (ad + bc)^2$$
which is true, for real $a,b,c,d$. So we're done.